# How can i get local timezone in ios?

Tags: ios, timezone

I need to set local timezones as per the location of the ios device.

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

or

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GTC+5.30"]];
```

is suited?

Comment: Do you try with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504843/get-current-iphone-device-timezone-date-and-time-from-utc-5-timezone-date-and-ti OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186666/get-timezone-country-from-iphone

Comment: `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` ?

Answer (score 11):

```
// get current date/time
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);
```

You can get the name of the local time zone using:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *tzName = [timeZone name];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
    NSString *strDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";

    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // input date is UTC date time, need to convert that time
    // to user's own local device timezone to get correct date
    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterUTC = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterUTC setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    [dateFormatterUTC setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // get UTC Date first
    NSDate* utcDate = [dateFormatterUTC dateFromString:strDate];

    // get local date from UTC Date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterLocal setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    [dateFormatterLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    // get final local date calculated by offsetting UTC Date
    NSDate *localDate = [dateFormatterUTC dateFromString:[dateFormatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];

    NSDate *localNowDate = [dateFormatterUTC dateFromString:[dateFormatterLocal stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-07-16 07:33:01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

NSDate *destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date] autorelease];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
[dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
[dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  
dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
NSLog(@"DateString : %@", dateStr);

- (Courtesy: Yuvaraj.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localTimeZone class method of NSTimeZone class to get a relative time zone object that decodes itself to become the default time zone for any locale in which it finds itself.

SRC: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/localTimeZone

If you need latitude and longitude: Get the official time zone database at http://www.iana.org/time-zones. Download tzdata2013g.tar.gz. There's a file in that archive named zone.tab that gives a lat/long for each time zone, for example:

```
 CH      +4723+00832     Europe/Zurich
```

The +4723+00832 indicates latitude = +47º23", longitude = +8º23"
(SRC:[Get Timezone/country from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186666/get-timezone-country-from-iphone))